# Error message when trying to run the parcel command. (Windows Powershell)

Tags: npm, package.json, parceljs

I am trying to install parcel as I begin learning React.  When I set up my files and try to use parcel in the powershell command line, it gives me this error.  I don't know what to do.

Package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/github/project.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/github/project/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/github/project#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

What I have installed:

```
npm install -g parcel@next
npm install --save react react-dom
```

[image: Error I get]

Answer (score 2):

Installing older version helped me:

```
npm install -g parcel-bundler@1.12.3
```

Then

```
parcel index.html
```

works.

Comment: I have done by this npm install -g parcel-bundler@latest thanks @Alexander Yashyn

Answer (score 0):

run the command with the npx utility, i.e. `npx parcel index.html`.